# Error in gfortran compilation : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: architecture, undefined, x86-64, gfortran

The programs have been compiled successfully using ifort. However, I don't know why I have the following error message in gfortran compilation.

Could you let me know how to solve this problem as below showed? Thank you!

```
gfortran main.o climate.o weather.o vegetation.o biogeochem.o initial.o humidity.o \
    radiation.o readpars.o canopy.o physiology.o snow.o soil.o utilities.o \
    ctemfire.o disturbance.o diagnostics.o io-cfs.o ies-io.o math.o stats.o nag-soil.o \
    -m64 -ffixed-line-length-132 -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf -o ibis

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "_time_", referenced from:

      _MAIN__ in main.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [ibis] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. The "time" function is an intrinsic function in ifort. I have change "time" to "dtime" for gfortran.

Michael